# Factor out invariant code from Plot

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning

Given a simple Gaussian kernel

```
UnscaledKernel[a_, b_, sigma_] := 
 Exp[-(((a - b)/sigma).((a - b)/sigma))/2]
```

and un-normalized smoothing function

```
Smooth[valCountLst_, val_, sigma_] := 
  Sum[valCountLst[[i]][[2]]*
    UnscaledKernel[{valCountLst[[i]][[1]]}, {val}, sigma], {i, 1, 
    Length[valCountLst]}];
```

and a normalization constant so that the integral on the defined domain is 1:

```
ScalingFactor[valCountLst_, sigma_, lower_, upper_] := 
 Integrate[
  Smooth[valCountLst, everyVal, sigma], {everyVal, lower, upper}]
```

From this unsmoothed data (that is, 1000 items at value 0 and 10 items at value 1):

```
testList = {{0, 1000}, {1, 10}};
```

**I'm plotting smoothed (un-normalized) data takes 0.024 seconds:**

```
Plot[N[Log[Smooth[testList, x, 0.2]]], {x, 0, 1.0}] // Timing
```

(output is `{0.024, THEFIGURE}`).

**When plotting the smoothed, normalized data, it takes much longer, 13.09 seconds:**

```
Plot[N[Log[
    Smooth[testList, x, 0.2]/ScalingFactor[testList, 0.2]]], {x, 0, 
   1.0}] // Timing
```

**This seems strange since the scaling factor takes only 0.044 seconds to compute.**

My conclusion is that Mathematica is computing the scaling factor *for every point, even though it does not depend on the point value x*.

**Is there a way to help Mathematica compute this expression once and factor it out (or memoize it)?**

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also use the `Evaluated -> True` undocumented option:

```
Plot[N[Log[Smooth[testList, x, 0.2]/ScalingFactor[testList, 0.2]]], 
      {x, 0, 1.0}, Evaluated -> True]
```

Please note that I had modified your definition of `ScalingFactor` to

```
ScalingFactor[valCountLst_, sigma_] := Integrate[ Smooth[valCountLst, x, sigma], {x, 0, 1}]
```

because you're calling it with the wrong number of parameters in your question

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a way to help *Mathematica* compute this expression once and factor it out (or memoize it)?

I'd use `With[]`, like so:

```
With[{sc = ScalingFactor[testList, 0.2]},
     Plot[Log[Smooth[testList, x, 0.2]/sc], {x, 0, 1}]
```